# Javascript and jquery stop event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a small issue:

I have a jquery onclick event set for a row() in a table and in the last column I have a link that opens a confirmation pop-up(asking if I am sure to do that bla bla . . .). If I click the link, the pop-up opens, and if I press no, it should stay on the current page, but instead it continues with the event from the row(that click is triggered). What do you think?

Link:

```
<tr class="clickableRow" id="someId"> bgcolor="color">
   ..........
    <td>
     <a  href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="javascript:del_prompt('url');">                        <img src="images/delete.png" border="0"></a>
</td>
</tr>
```

Javascript:

```
  $(".clickableRow").click(function() {
   window.open("companynewestimate.php?id="+this.id,"_parent");
  });
```

Del function

```
<script language="javascript">
function del_prompt(id)
{

        if(confirm ("Are you sure you want to delete selected Record")){
            location.href = "companyopenestimates.php?act=del&id="+id;
            }
        else{ 
            return false;
        }

        }



</script>
```

Comment: Sounds like not returning false from the click handler is the issue. But can't say for sure without seeing your code.

Comment: I want to trigger the popup and after, if I click no, not to follow the jquery event...I've posted some code...thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without some code, it's hard to get the correct answer. But maybe this helps:

```
  $("#element").on("click",function(e){
     //do something
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();
  })
```

See here:
http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: I want to trigger the popup and after, if I click no, not to follow the jquery event...

Comment: yeah, so you still could use preventDefault and stopPropagation. If the user clicks no, you could trigger a new click event.

By the way, it's actually not a good idea to use a popup. Maybe an overlay would be better. Or an alert box or something.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your link's `onclick` should do the trick:

```
onClick="del_prompt('<?=$line['id_est']?>'); return false;"
```

Note that the `javascript:` is not at all needed.

Comment: can you post your `del_prompt()` function? Maybe the problem is in there.